# Layering two different types of plots into one using faceting and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, facet-wrap

Data

[image]

**Code that I wrote for the plot:**

```
ggplot(summary_df_cont, aes(x=continent, y=total_cases, fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~type)
```

gives me

[image]

MY QUESTION:
 1. Is there anyway that I can merge 'confirmed' and 'recovered' levels (of type column) into one bar?
 2. And ,then use `geom_line()` to plot the third level (i.e., 'death') into the same graph?

TO MAKE IT LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

[image]

Thanks a lot guys, and sorry for the crappy framing of the question.

Comment: Please provide the data in `dput(data)` format

Comment: Side-comment: this looks like COVID19 data. Be careful that confirmed cases includes all patients who have been diagnosed, including the recovered or dead and not only the currently infected patients. So the bars in your histogram should **not** be stacked. Try dropping the facet and using position="dodge"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to massage your data a little.
1. Convert your table to long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and use only the "Confirmed" and "Recovered" columns. Name the new column as "combined"
2. Then plot the combined column as `geom_bar()` and plot the "Deaths" column as `geom_line()`